# Azure AD prevent user access

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm a support engineer and have not worked with Azure a lot but have done quite a bit of research regarding azure issues. To give some context I have a client that says his company's users are able to access the AD even though they are not assigned to an admin role. I have checked all admin roles and just certain admins are assigned, yet a normal user have access. Any ideas on what to look at? Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to block non admin users to be able to access azure ad administration portal.

If that is what you would like to achieve, then you can restrict the non-admin users to access azure ad admin portal through the below setting,

1. Login to azure portal
2. Navigate to azure active directory
3. Click on users on your left
4. Click on user settings
5. toggle the switch to 'yes' for 'administration portal'

[image: Settings snippet]

[image: Setting description]

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.
Thanks!